# error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Работаю в Intellij IDEA.

Выставил уровни:

```
ctrl+shift+alt (Project Structure) -> Sources -> Language level : 7
ctrl+shift+alt (Project Structure) -> Project -> Project language level : 7
ctrl+alt (Setting) -> Compiler -> Java Compiler : 1.7
```

**Sources code:**

```
public void setLogProperty(String pathLogProperties) {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathLogProperties);) {
    ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Проект собирается из IDE? Если это проект gradle, то будет использовано значение *sourceCompatibility* из build.gradle.

Comment: Да в IDE, использую Apache Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил добавив в pom.xml следующие строки:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

в настройках IDEA в поиске напиши `JAVA compiler` затем в поле `Target bytecode version` поменяй на `1.8`

Comment: Я выставлял 1.7, не помогло.
Для try with resources достаточно 1.7
Спасибо.

Comment: если мой ответ помог вам не забудьте оценит